# Can I connect the UPS neutral to my mains neutral permanently?

Tags: power-backup

I am trying to wireup a UPS (old one bought for my PC once) to power one of my ceiling lamps so it works as an emergency light. (Stupid idea? Yeah? :P)

But since the ceiling lamp wiring is already done and in place, I have only access to its switch where you only have the live wire. The neutral runs as common for all other lights on that circuit.

Since I want to power this specific light from the UPS, how am I going to get its neutral sorted? I read somewhere that you should never connect the output of the UPS to its input (may be on its user's manual).

If I connect the UPS and mains neutrals together, will it end up in chaos? Please advice. Thank you.

See the diagram below:
[image]

Comment: If the neutral is just a straight wire through the UPS, then this would have no effect. If not, then this would be a very bad idea. I wouldn't connect the neutral at all. (Of course, this may be a bad idea for other reasons.)

Comment: @DanielGriscom Oh I didn't know it could be a straight through connection. Looks like I need to take the UPS apart and have a look. Or may be just use a multi meter?

Comment: It would probably be obvious upon disassembly, but a multimeter could also be used. But again, this may be a bad idea for other reasons (as in this almost certainly isn't to code).

Comment: Can you not get a dedicated emergency light fixture, or emergency ballast with built-in backup supply?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes I can and I have such lamps too. But I just wanted to use the existing ceiling lamps, hence the UPS.

Comment: @DanielGriscom I didn't have to open up the UPS. Just connected only the live wire and voila it worked! So the neutral was a straight through as you said :) Please add your comment as an answer so I can give you reps. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the neutral is just a straight wire through the UPS, and it almost certainly is, then this would have no effect. If not, then this would be a very bad idea. I wouldn't connect the neutral at all. (Of course, this may be a bad idea for other reasons, not the least of which is it would certainly violate code.)

Comment: Actually, if the neutral runs straight through, then re-connecting it would create a parallel neutral, which is bad (and against code).